quotient space in inner product space
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $W\subset H$ be a closed subspace with finite codimension, say 2. It is well-known that the quotient space $H/W$ is isomorphic to orthogonal complement of $W$.
Let $X\subset H$ be a (dense) subspace which is not closed. Now it is assumed that $X/X\cap W$ is two dimensional subspace, so $X=X\cap W+V$ with $V$ being two dimensional space, $V\cap X\cap W=0$ and $V\subset X$. It is also given that $X\cap W^{\perp}$ is one dimensional. My question is, can we conclude that the assumption is wrong? Since $V$ cannot be $X\cap W^{\perp}$, and $X\cap W+X\cap W^{\perp}$ is proper subset of $X$, so if $V$ is spanned by a vector in $X\cap W^{\perp}$ and one more vector from somewhere, how can the extra vector come from?

The assumptions in question are not inconsistent. The following is a concrete example. Let $H = l^2$, $W = \{e_0, \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e_n\}^\perp$. Then $W \subset H$ is closed and of co-dimension $2$. Let $X = c_{00} \subset H$ (the space of finitely-supported sequences), which is dense but not closed. Then $X \cap W$ is of co-dimension $2$ in $X$ - indeed, you can choose $V = \text{span}\{e_0, e_1\}$. It is not hard to verify that $V \cap W = 0$. Furthermore, for any $n \geq 2$, $\frac{1}{n}e_1 - e_n \in X \cap W$, so $e_n \in V + (X \cap W)$. Thus, $X = V + (X \cap W)$. But $X \cap W^\perp$ is one-dimensional - indeed, $W^\perp = \text{span}\{e_0, \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e_n\}$, so $X \cap W^\perp = \text{span}\{e_0\}$ has dimension $1$.

In a sense, this is really not that surprising. It is perhaps better to adopt a different perspective: a co-dimension $2$ closed subspace $W \subset H$ is determined by two linearly independent continuous linear functionals $\phi, \psi$ - that is to say, $W = \ker(\phi) \cap \ker(\psi)$. On a Hilbert space, $\phi = (h, \cdot)$ and $\psi = (k, \cdot)$ for some linearly independent vectors $h, k \in H$. Thus, $W^\perp = \text{span}\{h, k\}$ has dimension $2$. Now, if $X \subset H$ is dense, $W \cap X$ is still determined by two continuous linear functionals - $W \cap X = \ker(\phi|_X) \cap \ker(\psi|_X)$. $\phi|_X$ and $\psi|_X$ are still linearly independent, due to density of $X$, so $W \cap X$ is still of co-dimension $2$ in $X$. But there’s no longer any reason $W^\perp \cap X = \text{span}\{h, k\} \cap X$ is of dimension $2$ anymore, since $h, k$ may not be elements of $X$. Indeed, you can have all three possibilities - if $h, k$ are both in $X$, then $W^\perp \cap X$ is of dimension $2$; if only one of them is in $X$, then $W^\perp \cap X$ is of dimension $1$; if $\text{span}\{h, k\} \cap X = 0$, then $W^\perp \cap X$ is of dimension $0$.
The above can be adapted to any finite co-dimension, i.e., if $W \subset H$ is of finite co-dimension $n$ and $X \subset H$ is dense, then $W \cap X$ is of co-dimension $n$ in $X$, but $W^\perp \cap X$ can have any dimension from $0$ to $n$.

Incidentally, this tells you $X = W \oplus W^\perp$ is not true if $W$ is a closed subspace of a general inner product space $X$, without assuming $X$ is a Hilbert space. In fact, the above shows this is not true even when $W$ has finite co-dimension. (Though, funnily enough, it is actually true when $W$ has finite dimension.)

Very detailed answer. Thank you!
